# Using wget to download from site with DDos protection

Tags: wget, denial-of-service

When trying to load pages with wget I have the following error:

```
 $ wget --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)" "https://www.cruisersforum.com/forums/"
--2020-12-19 22:36:44--  https://www.cruisersforum.com/forums/
Resolving www.cruisersforum.com (www.cruisersforum.com)... 172.67.75.74, 104.26.0.68, 104.26.1.68
Connecting to www.cruisersforum.com (www.cruisersforum.com)|172.67.75.74|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
2020-12-19 22:36:46 ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable.
```

When using Firefox to access the same URL I get in the browser:

[image]

How to wget urls from site with this check? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open a new tab and hit F12 and switch to network tab then go to  `https://www.cruisersforum.com/forums/` . You'll se a request with the link of the page right click on it and hit copy then copy as cURL. This will copy a curl request that you can use just add a `-O` at the and to make it download to the disk. That works with cURL rather than wget but result will be the same.

Comment: wget was just a test. I plan to use Python BeautifulSoup lib. to extract forum post texts. CloudFare will check access for every url I request. How to get around CloudFare using BeautifulSoup lib.?